# Unable to instantiate manager classes via service container

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder if any of you faced the same issue before. Currently all Illuminate manager classes do not contain application class in the constructor:

```
vendor/illuminate//auth/AuthManager.php:    public function __construct($app)
vendor/illuminate//auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php:    public function __construct($app)
vendor/illuminate//broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php:    public function __construct($app)
vendor/illuminate//cache/CacheManager.php:    public function __construct($app)
vendor/illuminate//database/DatabaseManager.php:    public function __construct($app, ConnectionFactory $factory)
vendor/illuminate//filesystem/FilesystemManager.php:    public function __construct($app)
vendor/illuminate//queue/QueueManager.php:    public function __construct($app)
vendor/illuminate//support/Manager.php:    public function __construct($app)
vendor/illuminate//support/ServiceProvider.php:    public function __construct($app)
```

Therefore, it's impossible to instantiate them directly via service container – Laravel's SC cannot resolve $app just based on the variable name. Normal bootstrap process manually instantiates them and injects the application container. But there are cases, like mine, where I want to ask for a class later on.

In this app of mine, laravel-aws-worker, I need a queue worker instance in one of the controller methods. Queue worker depends on queue manager, queue manager is not instantiable – type hinting breaks (throws a BindingResolutionException).

My current workaround is to manually bind the queue manager during boot:

```
    $this->app->singleton(QueueManager::class, function() {
        return new QueueManager($this->app);
    });
```

But I wonder if there is a better way, or if there are plans to add a type (an interface?) to Illuminate constructors.